# How to create struct with embedded generic member?

Tags: generics, rust

I want to use the [`leveldb` crate](https://github.com/skade/leveldb) where I embed a `Database` struct inside a larger struct to be used in different places in my code:

My naïve approach would be:

```
extern crate leveldb;
use leveldb::database::Database;

pub struct Model {
  db: Database,
}
```

But this leads to `expected one type argument` error, so I have tried doing what the compiler told me and arrived at this, but it still fails:

```
extern crate leveldb;
extern crate db_key;

use leveldb::database::Database;
use db_key::Key;

pub struct Model<K>
{
    db: Database<K>,
}
```

Now it looks as if I need to somehow bind the `K` parameter, but I'm unsure how. I suppose I could fix this by writing some kind of instantiator of `Model` that would pin `K`, but I have no idea how.

I managed to get this far:

```
pub struct Model<D> {
    db: D,
}

impl<D> Model<D> where D: {
    pub fn open(path: String) -> Model<D> {
        let path = Path::new("/tmp/test");
        let mut options = Options::new();
        options.create_if_missing = true;
        let database = match Database::open(path, options) {
            Ok(db) => { db },
            Err(e) => { panic!("failed to open database: {:?}", e) }
        };

        Model {
            db: database,
        }
    }
}
```

But now Rust complains about `expected type parameter D, found struct model::leveldb::database::Database`. I was expecting it to figure out that `D` was bound to `Database`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I've read the answer, but what I can't figure out is that the `Database` comes with another generic parameter (`K`) which needs to be bound as well somehow. I don't know how to write a reasonable where clause for that.

Comment: I've tried stuff like `pub fn open(path: String) -> Model<K> where K: db_key::Key {...}` where `Model` uses `K`, but then Rust wants me to add a lifetime. That seems weird.

Comment: It seems that I can just declare the db field like this: `db: Database<i32>`, but how was I supposed to know that?

Comment: database require that its K implement Key trait, https://docs.rs/db-key/0.0.5/db_key/trait.Key.html, if you look Key is implement for i32, why ? I have literally no idea I have no knowledge about leveldb. Rust is not a language like javascript(random language pick) where you can start by doing some database stuff and expect understand everything. Specially the learning curse of Rust is not friendly, you could read the book for start https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/, but known that Rust require a lot of learning time.